# How can I get my full width jQuery image fader to be responsive?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a jquery script that fades through images with a full browser width and height:

**CSS:**

```
#wrap{
    position:fixed;
    z-index:-1; 
    top:0; 
    left:0; 
    background-color:black
}
#wrap img.bgfade{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    display:none;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    z-index:-1
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="wrap">
<img class="bgfade" src="/images/homepage/splash/1.jpg">
<img class="bgfade" src="/images/homepage/splash/2.jpg">
<img class="bgfade" src="/images/homepage/splash/3.jpg">
<img class="bgfade" src="/images/homepage/splash/4.jpg">
<img class="bgfade" src="/images/homepage/splash/5.jpg">
<img class="bgfade" src="/images/homepage/splash/6.jpg">
<img class="bgfade" src="/images/homepage/splash/7.jpg">
<img class="bgfade" src="/images/homepage/splash/8.jpg">
<img class="bgfade" src="/images/homepage/splash/9.jpg">
<img class="bgfade" src="/images/homepage/splash/10.jpg">
<img class="bgfade" src="/images/homepage/splash/11.jpg">
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
<script>
$(window).load(function(){
$('img.bgfade').hide();
var dg_H = $(window).height();
var dg_W = $(window).width();
$('#wrap').css({'height':dg_H,'width':dg_W});
function anim() {
    $("#wrap img.bgfade").first().appendTo('#wrap').fadeOut(1500);
    $("#wrap img").first().fadeIn(4000);
    setTimeout(anim, 7500);
}
anim();})
$(window).resize(function(){window.location.href=window.location.href})
</script>
```

This works a treat, but it is not responsive :-(

I can't use

`background-size: cover;` *OR* `background-position: center;`

because it is not a background.

How else can I scale the image when the browser is resized or viewed on a iPhone/iPad etc without it looking like below:

At present it looks so odd scaled:

[distored image from my upload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAn3K.jpg)

This site, manages it fine (but my script isn't looking for background images unfortunately):

http://www.britishactionacademy.com/

Any help here would be much appreciated. Thanks! :-)

Comment: Add `html, body { width: 100%, height: 100% }` to your css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you stick to images you could use `object-fit: cover;` on your `img` tag...  But since `object-fit` is not well supported yet across browsers... you can use

**`DIV` and `background-size: cover;`**

And use **CSS3** for the fade animation using `transition`, `visibility` and `opacity`

```js
$(".bgfade").each(function() {
  
  var $slides = $(this).find(">div"),
      n = $slides.length,
      c = 0;
  
  function anim(){
    $slides.removeClass("active").eq(c++%n).addClass("active");
  }
  
  anim();                  // First run
  setInterval(anim, 3000); // Loop
  
});
```

```css
/*QuickReset*/*
{box-sizing:border-box}html,body{margin:0;height:100%;}

/* BGFADE */
.bgfade{
  position: fixed; 
  z-index: -1; 
  top: 0;
  left: 0; 
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #000;
}
/* BGFADE SLIDES */
.bgfade > div {
  background: none 50%; /* Set background-image trough HTML */
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 1s; -webkit-transition: 1s;   /* Add animation transition */
}
/* .active is handled by jQuery */
.bgfade > div.active{
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="bgfade">
  <div style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/800x600/0bf?text=Hello')"></div>
  <div style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/800x600/fb0?text=World!')"></div>
  <div style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/800x600/bf0?text=This')"></div>
  <div style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/800x600/0fb?text=is')"></div>
  <div style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/800x600/f0b?text=cool!')"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#wrap').css({'height':dg_H,'width':dg_W})
```

Width and height are calculated when `$(window).load`. They are static in `px`.

Try this instead:

```
$('#wrap').css({'height':'100%','width':'100%'});
```

Comment: Still no change I am afraid :-(